# ok-cancel button in prompt in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, prompt

How to handle ok-cancel button in prompt in asp.net?I want to when click on cancel,I can do a new job?
this is my code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return a();"  Text="Button" />

function  a()
{
    var s = prompt("hello");
    if (s != 123) {
        alert("enter number correctly");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: as@echilon suggested or i would prefer using this jPrompt/jAlert/jConfirm plugin 
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cancel the postback you need to `return false`, otherwise `true` (so the opposite):

```
function  a()
{
    var s = prompt("hello");
    if (s != 123) {
        alert("enter number correctly");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way would be to use [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this task using confirm box :-

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return disp_confirm();"  Text="Button" />
```

Use this script on button press :-

```
function disp_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using JavaScript than the following from [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm) will do exactly what's required. Otherwise there are some very good and established JQuery plugins that can give you pretty much endless options.

`if (confirm("Your question")) { 
 // do things if OK
}`